# Compilation failure error while triggering the job in Jenkins

Tags: maven, compiler-errors, jenkins-pipeline, ear

I'm getting the below error  while triggering the job in Jenkins for EAR application. Can anyone help to fix the issue?

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project and cannot access org.quartz.Job

class file for org.quartz.Job not found.

I've tried in Enterprise Jenkins and error I'm getting in code coverage stage.

Note: Checkout code from RTC.

Comment: I assume that you are missing a dependency to quartz lib?

Comment: in pom.xml @khmarbaise

Comment: Yes of cource you need it there because are trying to compile against it ... so it must be on the class path...